# Selecting a pumping rate for a population inversion

Tags: optics, laser

I'm trying to make a plot (on mathematica) of population inversion vs time for a ruby laser including the time dependence in the formula given below. The pumping rate is given by

r*exp(-(t-dt/[Delta]t)^2), where dt=2 and [Delta]t=0.1.

I'm using the following rate equations for a 3 level system(A21 is the relaxation from level 2 to 1 and R13 is the pumping rate from level 1 to 3):

```
n1'[t] == A21*n2[t] + R13*(n3[t] - n1[t]
n2'[t] == A32*n3[t] - A21*n2[t]
n3'[t] == -A32*n3[t] - R13 (n3[t] - n1[t]
boundary conditions: n1[0] == 100, n2[0] == 0, n3[0] == 0
```

In my plot I need to select the pumping rate so that the pulse excites a population inversion of unity, which I'm not too sure of how to select this number? My assumption was that r=5 by looking at the graph, so I used that when solving the differential equations but I'm not sure how this will help me select R13 for the plot?

I am also given that the photon lifetime tau2=500*tau3

[image]